# RubyGems installing wrong code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I install the gem `ipa_reader` the code does not install correctly. In the file `/lib/ipa_reader/ipa_file.rb`, the code that I get is

`Zip::ZipFile.foreach(file_path) { |f| info_plist_file = f if f.name.match(regex) }` .
Which I guess is from an older version. 
What I should get, and what shows up on github is

`Zip::File.foreach(file_path) { |f| info_plist_file = f if f.name.match(regex) }.`

What is going on?

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.4'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

group :development do
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'pry-rails'
end

gem 'CFPropertyList', '~> 2.1.1'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'rufus-scheduler'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'ipa_reader' , '~> 0.7.1'
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear...

Comment: @MrYoshiji code I get when installing the gem is `Zip::ZipFile` it should be `Zip::File`

Comment: Whats the output of `bundle show ipa_reader`

Comment: @Magnuss the code that I am getting and posted above is the result of `bundle show ipa_reader`. Thats how I found it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are installing from rubygems you are downloading stable 0.7.1 version, while at github there is latest development version. If you want to use this one (although it is not recommended to live on the bleeding edge), specify git url in your gemfile

`gem 'ipa_reader', git: 'https://github.com/schlu/Ipa-Reader.git'`

refer here for more info http://bundler.io/v1.3/git.html

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a mistake from the gem author.
A github repo is not synched to rubygems, so the gem published to rubygems does not necessarily have to be the exact same thing as on github.

You can easily tell bundler to user the code from github, by doing:

```
gem 'ipa_reader', github: 'schlu/Ipa-Reader'
```